# emacs flycheck syntax checker pylint can't config

Tags: python, emacs, pylint

I installed flycheck in emacs and set checker to pylint, encountered the following error. Python 3.8

how can fix this problem?

```
Suspicious state from syntax checker python-pylint: Flycheck checker python-pylint returned 1, but its output contained no errors:   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys;sys.path.pop(0);import runpy;runpy.run_module(\pylint\)
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Try installing a more recent version of python-pylint, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!
```

Comment: Reinstall Python 3.7 solved the problem, and previous Python version was 3.8.